Get Transparent BSDF to work in Cycles as it is working in Eevee
I'm unable to make the Transparent BSDF work in Cycles the way it it working in Eevee. I have the same node setup for both and in case of Cycles it is rendering the parts that should be transparent as black. I'm not able to figure out what settings I need to change.
Node setup (same for Cycles and Eevee):

Renders:



The image on the right looks like there is Bloom enabled for the glowing part. Are you sure left is Eevee and right is Cycles? Because Bloom is only available in Eevee, and transparency is also usually not black in Cycles but in Eevee, if you do not change the Blend Mode.

Yes, the image on the right is from Cycles. I updated the question to showcase the render engines and settings as well.

Are you adding Glare in the Compositor? Because otherwise I do not understand the glowing effect. And I don't understand why there is no glow in Eevee, since Bloom is enabled and the Glare in compositing would work for both render engines. Do you have too few bounces set under Light Paths? Or overlapping geometry? I could try to ask dozens of questions but it does not make sense to me from the screenshots. Maybe you should upload your file here https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question for further inspection.

Thanks. Updated the question with my blend file. Some minor parts have changed from my screenshot renders as I am continuously working on the file but the overall issue persists.

Okay, the glow which was confusing me was obviously just the light bouncing off the background (which does not occur in Eevee, since mesh lights do not interact with their environment there, only in Cycles).
For the black parts, I could not see in your question that you have over 3000 faces there. So the problem is as I assumed in my last comment: much too few bounces, in this case for Transparent you have only 8 - which means after 8 layers of transparency, light is blocked and it shows black.
To solve this, go to the Render Properties tab, under Light Paths > Max Bounces_ increase the value for Transparent. It seems that 64 is enough, with 32 there is still a small black area left. To make sure there will be nothing black from any view you even go higher, but more bounces also mean longer render times.


This is amazing! Thank you so much.
